# Trivial Set Proofs

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I would be grateful if you could help with the following. (where *P* is the *'Potenzmenge'*)

*X* and *Y* are non-empty sets and *X ∩ Y = ∅* and *F: P(X) x P(Y) -> P(X ∪ Y)*

and *(A, B) -> (X\A) ∪ (Y\B)*

Show that:

1. F is surjective
2. F is injective.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @SirJective Elements of $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$ resp., i.e. subsets of $X$ and $Y$ resp.

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that function $G:\wp(X\cup Y)\to\wp(X)\times\wp(Y)$ prescribed by:  $$Z\mapsto\langle X\setminus Z,Y\setminus Z)$$

serves as inverse of function $F$.

A function is surjective and injective if and only if it is invertible.